# Hyphen usage with expressions in compound adjectives

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

Compound adjectives are hyphenated, e.g. "data-to-field binding". But how is the hyphen used when one of the words in the compound adjective is an expression? For example, how would you hyphenate the following:

> (Data) (to) (service environment) binding?
>
> Data-to-service-environment binding?
>
> Data-to-service environment binding?

Comment: I agree with Gulliver's answer. Just one small point - not all compound adjectives are hyphenated, for example "headstrong", "threadbare", watertight" and quiet a few others.

Comment: En dashes to the rescue. We've had this question in the past. Several times, in fact. En dashes to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

English does not really have an elegant solution to this.

I think *data-to-service-environment binding* is technically correct, even if it in unwieldy. *Data-to-SE binding* might be better.

Macmillan suggests an "[all-or-nothing](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/anti-multiple-hyphen-tendencies)" approach as there are cases where ambiguity could impact meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Hyphenation is complex and often subjective. The Macmillan article mentioned in another answer is only a general statement about hyphenation where there is a straightforward approach.

The *Chicago Manual of Style* has three pages of general exposition *and* a twelve-page chart devoted to it.

Jumping ahead to my conclusion, my most likely understanding of the meaning of the sentence results in this *particular* example being hyphenated as follows:

> Data-to-service environment binding.

But that's based on my subjective interpretation of the *meaning* of the sentence. Without further context, it's impossible to say. The question needs to provide more context for a more definitive answer.

A detailed analysis follows.

---

> I am eating a to-die-for ice cream sandwich.

Here, the phrase *to die for* is hyphenated because it's acting adjectivally to the noun *ice cream sandwich*.

*Ice cream* is an open compound word. Unlike some other words, such as *online*, it has remained open rather than being hyphenated or closed. Although the online version of Merriam-Webster doesn't provide an online definition of *ice cream sandwich*, Oxford Dictionaries [*does*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ice_cream_sandwich).

Neither *ice-cream sandwich* nor *ice cream-sandwich* would be appropriate for reasons of syntax and simple idiomatic usage—and its open-format appearance in some dictionaries like Oxford.

So, the phrase *ice cream sandwich* remains in an open form and other adjectives are applied to it.

> I am eating a chocolate ice cream sandwich.

Here, there is only a single adjective and nothing is hyphenated.

> I am eating a dark chocolate ice cream sandwich.

Again, hyphenation would not normally be applied.

Hyphenation is normally used when a phrase could be ambiguous without it, or when a component of the phrase has a series of words that are closely related to each other.

But like *ice cream* or *ice cream sandwich*, *dark chocolate* is *also* an open-form noun. (It is similarly seen in an entry at [*Oxford*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dark_chocolate).)

While *to die for* does have an entry in some dictionaries ([Oxford again](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to_die_for)), it is a *phrase* rather than an open-form noun. When used adjectivally in front of a noun, common guidelines say that it should be hyphenated:

> It is a to-die-for chocolate ice cream sandwich.

Note that common guidelines also say that there should be no hyphenation if it comes *after* the noun:

> It is a chocolate ice cream sandwich that is to die for.

---

When hyphenating multiple yet discrete phrases, it's common to keep the hyphenation within the context of each phrase.

Each of the following are discrete adjectival phrases:

> It was a high-profile synopsis.
>   It was a book-length synopsis.

But what happens when those adjectives are combined?

Depending on punctuation, here are a few different options:

> It was a high-profile, book-length synopsis.
>   It was a high-profile and book-length synopsis.
>   It was a high-profile book-length synopsis.

It would be very uncommon to see it expressed as a fully joined adjectival phrase:

> It was a high-profile-book-length synopsis.

Most editors would remove the middle hyphen and replace it with a comma or (less frequently) *and*.

---

Returning to your actual question.

> Data-to-field binding.

This is clear.

> Data-to-service binding

This is also clear.

> Data-to-environment binding.

This follows the same pattern as the others, so makes sense.

> Data-to-service-to-environment binding.

This makes equal sense.

But *data to service environment binding* presents a difficulty.

In looking at the phrase, it's not clear if either *environment binding* or *service environment* is being used as an open-form noun—or if there is no open-form noun involved at all.

One of these is correct, without the addition of the *data to* text:

- (service) (environment binding).
- (service environment) (binding).
- service-environment (binding).
- (service) ([, | and]) (environment) (binding).

Until it's known *which* of these is correct, it's not possible to say how "data to" should be incorporated.

My own subjective feel for this (which could be wrong) is that *environment binding* is being used as an open-form noun.

This seems natural:

> (Open-form noun) I applied **an** environment binding.

Whereas this seems less likely:

> (Adjective and noun) I applied **an** environment[al] binding.

The first seems most likely simply because of how it's spelled. If it were meant to be used as an *adjective* (as opposed to part of an open-form noun) it should be spelled *environmental*.

Assuming this is the case, then the following also seems likely:

> I applied **a** service-based environment binding.
>   I applied **a** data-to-service environment binding.

Otherwise, we could also have something like this in addition to the other possible hyphenations presented in the question:

> I applied **a** service-based and environmental binding.
>   I applied **a** data-to-service and environmental binding.

But the question can't really be answered with a greater level of certainty without knowing the meaning behind the individual words in the first place.

Comment: I thought I formulated the question well enough by using parentheses. I was specifically looking for expertise on how to hyphenate a compound adjective when one of its components is multi-word. Delving into the meaning of the particular example is probably not as important in this case.